# PL SQL - Define Dynamically Global Cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

There are two cursor at top in package

```
cursor cur1()
   select 1 from dual;

cursor cur2()
   select 2 from dual;
```

I have a loop as below, i try to set cur1 or cur2 dynamically.

```
for row1 in cur1 -- or cur2
  ..
end loop;
```

OR can i generate the global cursor at top dynamically?

Comment: Can't you just have a ` IF THEN ELSE END IF` condition and open either of those, following a condition of your choosing ?

Comment: I thought this solution but i wonder is possible as dynamically setting?

Comment: How do you decide which cursor to use?

Comment: For example first cursor is cur_Android and second cursor is cur_IPhone. Then i wanna loop in first cursor [or second cursor]. Can i decide it dynamically?

Comment: But what is it that determines which cursor is run? Like, do you have a variable or something that holds a value of, say, "Android" or "Iphone"? If so, then you could use that in your if statement (e.g. `if v_phone_type = 'Android' then for row1 in cur1 ... elsif v_phone_type = 'Iphone' then for row1 in cur2 ...`. If the logic inside both cursor for loops, you could put that in a separate procedure and then call it from inside either loop.

Comment: I agree with you but my for-loop content is too long. So i dont want to write duplicate loop block. I try to solve in one for-loop. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the result sets from the two  cursors are the same columns and data types, you could do something like:

```
cursor cur(p_flag varchar2) is
  select 1 as value from dual
  where p_flag = 'iOS'
  union
  select 2 as value from dual
  where p_flag = 'Android';
```

and then

```
for row1 in cur('iOS')
  ...
end loop;
```

or

```
for row1 in cur('Android')
  ...
end loop;
```

where, presumably, the iOS/Android flag is actually a variable rather than a literal.

The flag check in each branch of the cursor's union makes that branch return no rows. Hopefully the optimiser will spot that immediately and short-circuit so it doesn't actually do any real work in the dead branch.

Quick demo:

```
declare
  cursor cur(p_flag varchar2) is
    select 1 as value from dual
    where p_flag = 'iOS'
    union
    select 2 from dual
    where p_flag = 'Android';

  l_flag varchar2(7);
begin
  l_flag := 'Android';

  for r in cur(l_flag) loop
    dbms_output.put_line('Cursor got: ' || r.value);
  end loop;
end;
/

Cursor got: 2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle provides the ref cursor construct to allow us to define cursors dynamically. Unfortunately we can't use a ref cursor in a FOR LOOP so we need to type a little bit more code.

```
declare
    rc sys_refcursor;
    switch varchar2(10) := 'iOS';
    lrec t23%rowtype; -- or define a RECORD type to match the required projection
begin
    -- in real life SWITCH would be a passed parameter
    if switch = 'iOS' then
         open rc for select * from t23;
    else
         open rc for select * from t42;  
    end if;
    loop
        fetch rc into lrec;
        exit when rc%notfound;
        dbms_output.put_line(lrec.id ||'::'||lrec.text);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Check out [the SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a1766/1).